# Need help in SQL constraints

Tags: sql-server, triggers, constraints, arcgis

I need your help in SQL server and let me explain my issue

We have two tables **Manholes** and **Basis**, which are related to each other by GlobalID/Guid fields. 
In the Manhole table i set coded value domain for *owner* field (1.Company 2.Unknown) and in Basis table another domain for *category* field (1.CRM_ID 2. None...).

My issue is to restrict our GIS editors to do following action: when they'll choose CRM_ID **from Basis** *category* field, editors couldn't be able to choose Unknown value **from Manholes** *owner* field.

Help me to solve this problem please, i hope my question is clear for you ;)

Comment: It sounds like you need a tutorial on SQL (the language, not the server). Foreign key constraints are a fundamental part of SQL. Have you tried searching for any tutorials? There are hundrends, some better than others. SO isn't the best place to ask for such things, as a tutorial on SQL would be too big to fit in a SO answer.

Comment: If you sheared the relevant tables DDL statements it would be much easier to help you.